# BeatsAudioManager randomly triggers "apisecurity"

Tags: beatsmusic

BeatsAudioManager randomly triggers "apisecurity" when trying to play a track. This happens about 30% of the time. If I wait a minute and try again, it works. The crossdomain.xml file appears to be loading. Any ideas of what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens infrequently and on an account basis only. We would need to address your issue, specifically. A generalized answer is not available. Please email us at beatsplatform@beatsmusic.com